# Urn problem: Describe the sample space with equally likely outcomes, describe the event A, and compute P(A)

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory

The problem is the following:

> We have an urn with $3$ green and $4$ yellow balls. We choose $2$ balls randomly without replacement. Let $A$ be the event that we have two different coloured balls. 
> (a) Describe a possible sample space with equally likely outcomes, and the event $A$ in your sample space. 
> (b) Compute $P(A)$

For $(a)$ on my first attempt, I said my sample space $S$ has two equally likely outcomes: select green, then yellow, and select yellow then green. Then I said $A = \{ (green,\ yellow), (yellow, \ green) \}$.

For $(b)$, I computed $P(A)$ to be $\dfrac47$, because there are $\binom72$ total possibilities, and $\binom31 \binom41$ desired outcomes.

I'm pretty sure I got $(b)$ correct. However, my answer to $(a)$ seemed very strange to me, because I would be saying that $A = S$. I am not saying that the answer is incoherent, just that it seems weird to me.

**Did I get both $(a)$ and $(b)$ correct? If not, what should I do?**

Comment: b) is right and a) is wrong.  For a) you want $\binom72=21$ equally likely outcomes in your sample space, $12$ of which are elements of event $A$.

Comment: @saulspatz I found that A = { (G1, Y1), (G1, Y2), (G1, Y3), (G1, Y4), (G2, Y1), (G2, Y2), (G2, Y3), (G2, Y4), (G3, Y1), (G3, Y2), (G3, Y3), (G3, Y4) }. How can S contain more? Selecting balls of the same color at random are not equally likely outcomes. P(G1, G2) != P(Y1, Y2) for instance.

Comment: You've ignored all the possibilities of choosing two balls of the same color.